# Does system auto detect serial voting here on meta?

Tags: support, voting

I know that the system detects serial voting that has happened on the main site. And, by the next day the votes are reversed.

But does the same happen here on meta too? Here, we do not have reputation changes involved with voting alright but serial voting can still happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, it does.

- A [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228609/260388) was asked on Meta Stack Exchange of which [answers says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228610/260388) "Yes, Serial voting detection script runs on all sites"
- A [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180/260388) posted suggesting to exclude exceptional case from detection of serial voting on child/parent meta sites was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) with [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151464/260388) from developer declaring no change of serial voting script behavior on meta sites from that of main sites.

This means auto detection of serial voting by system works on meta sites as well.

Comment: I hope your answer is correct. BTW the answer contained in the 2nd link of your answer isn't that convincing. Did you see the comment posted under that answer?